# Is there a generally considered standard for determining the proper ratio between PermGen and Heap space?

Tags: java, configuration, heap-memory

I know these parameters should be tuned based on your specific application but for a JBoss instance, I'm looking for a generally accepted ratio or max value for both the heap space and perm gen space. This would be what I use as a starting point and would tune later.

In my case, this is JBoss 5 on Java 1.6.

Comment: The heap depends on the amount of data you have and the perm gen is based on the amount of code you have.  There is no particular reason to believe one being high means the other is also.  BTW I suggest moving off Java 1.6 asap. It's been out of public support for five years, which is a potential security problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no golden ratio since Java applications come in all shapes and sizes. For a multi-tenant WebSphere EE server the PermGen will be huge due to dozens of enterprise WARs being loaded but for a small embedded system the PermGen should be decreased to absolute minimum. Another extreme would an in-memory database written in Java that hosts GBs of data but has relatively small PermGen.

PermGen is normally determined by the loaded classes. Unless there is a `ClassLoader` leak or bytecode generation libraries go bonkers generating millions of proxy class it's size shouldn't matter. GC on PermGen is rarely the slowest part of the full GC cycle.

Luckily with Java 8+ we now have MetaSpace instead of PermGen, and we don't have to size it anymore (although it's prudent to cap it).